# ServiceController Exception (Cannot control service on computer '.'.)

Tags: c#, windows

I am trying to send a command to my service TestService from a program running as administrator, I am able to start/stop it just fine, but whenever I try to ExecuteCommand() I encounter an Exception:

> Cannot control service on computer '.'.

```
        try
        {
            System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController service = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController("TestService");
            
            if (service.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
            {
                service.Start();
                service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running);
            }

            service.ExecuteCommand(100); // Causes Exception every time
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            throw e;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening is because ExecuteCommand only accepts integers: 128-256, anything under 128 is system reserved and since 100 is being passed the Exception occurs.

Replacing `service.ExecuteCommand(100)` with something like `service.ExecuteCommand(130)` will work just fine.